# 2-column layout: divs either equal to height of longest, or height of viewport

Tags: html, css, layout

So I've been trawling SO for an answer to my conundrum, and I know of course the whole chaos with faux-columns and backgrounds and overflow and negative margins but either I'm blind or nobody has solved this one yet.

The situation is very simple:

- The body is 100% width.
- I want a two-column layout.
- If the content in both columns is smaller than the viewport height, I want both columns to be the height of the viewport.
- If the content in either column is longer than the viewport height, I want both columns to be the height of the longest.

Is there no way to resolve this without too many CSS hacks? I don't mind terribly about backwards compatibility (for instance, I'm happy to use vw units), as long as the site doesn't fall apart completely in older browsers.

I'd post some example code but all I have so far is half a dozen files, each testing one of the popular solutions. The latest one is using vw:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;     /* This is used to reset any browser-default margins */
    height:100vh; /* This is needed to overcome a Chrome bug. */
    width:100vw;  /* As above. */
}
div {
    height:100vh;
}
#left {
    background:snow;
    float:left;
    width: 20vw;
}

#right {
    background:teal;
    float:right;
    width: 80vw;
}
```

This solves the first, viewport-height problem, but not the second, longest-column problem (as visible if you fill either column with content).

Comment: the only solution is with javascript http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

Comment: Actually this should be possible with a combination of `min-height` and `display: table`. Let me try a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with pure CSS. However, it will not work in IE7 because it requires the use of `display: table`, and this demo uses the css viewport units which don't work in IE7/8.

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/helion3/pen/IEKih)

- Setting a wrapper element to `display: table` and the two columns to
  `display: table-cell` means we can ensure that the columns remain equal in height
- Defining `min-height` doesn't work on table cells so we need an inner div that we can apply the min-height to. A bit of extra markup, but it solves the issue.
- The inner content div has a min-height of the browser viewport. If the height changes by css or content, the table columns will grow.

As a test, I left a commented `height` style so you can see what it looks like when scrolled.

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;

}
#wrapper>div {
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#wrapper>div:first-child {
    background:snow;
    width: 20vw;
}

#wrapper>div:last-child {
    background:teal;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 100%
}
#wrapper .content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*height: 2000px;*/
}
```